# Ctrl+Left / Right to skip word and stop at end / beginning of line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

When I press Ctrl+Left, the cursor moves to the next line after reaching the end of line.

Is there a way to configure this so that it ends at the end of line?

Application: IntelliJ, VSCode

EDIT:

End key is so far away from arrow keys. Sometimes I just want to skip word by word until the end of line and stop there. However, the behavior right now is to move to the next line.

I understand that Fn+arrow key is also an option but Fn key placement varies across keyboards. On Thinkpad it's on the left corner, and on a full sized keyborad it's on the right part of the keyboard. It makes it VERY difficult to become accustomed to one shortcut just to move to the beginning and end of line.

The only saving grace for moving to end/beginning of line is to just use Ctrl+arrow and wait until it stops. But this also continues to the next/beginning of line.

Comment: It might help if people knew what application you were using.  Keyboard shortcuts can vary depending on the application.

Comment: Doesn't pressing the End key do that?

Comment: End key is so far away from arrow keys. Sometimes I just want to skip word by word until the end of line and stop there. However, the behavior right now is to move to the next line.